# как добавить кодировку при отправки формы в php

Tags: php, javascript, form

Когда приходит результаты формы на email - то это выглядит не четаемо, как это можно исправить? я уже вписал кодировку но почему то продолжает приходить с поломаным текстом.
php:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Обратный вызов'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Имя: ".$_POST["name"]."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Телефон: ".$_POST["phone"]."\n"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

js:

```
$("#callbackForm").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "callback.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: $("#callbackForm input[name='name']").val(),
                    phone: $("#callbackForm input[name='phone']").val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#callbackForm input[name='name']").val(""),
                    $("#callbackForm input[name='phone']").val(""),
                    $("#subCallback").attr("value", "отправлено");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: что значит поломанным текстом? Возможно с самой формы текст приходит в другой кодировке, попробуйте добавить accept-charset="UTF-8" в саму форму `<form  action="" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: вот такое приходит на email п÷я─п╬п╪п╬п╨п╬п╢: 333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте кодировку в трех местах:

1) Кодировка отправителя (ваша форма). Установите ей в `header` кодировку `utf-8`. `<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>`.

2) Форма отправки. В форме отправки так же сделайте кодировку ввода по умолчанию `<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

3) Кодировка приёмника. Ваш `Callback.php`. В файле укажите для php следующую информацию: `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

Убедитесь, так же, что в настройках Вашего Nginx (Apache) выставлена кодировка utf-8.

Ну и ко всему прочему, сохраняйте Ваши исполняемые файлы в формате `UTF-8 without BOM`

Answer (score 0):

Надо в файле .htaccess написать:

```
AddDefaultCharset кодировка
```

Например:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8;
```